# QGIS - Layer Rendering Opacity not being kept when exporting atlas

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

I have changed the layer opacity of a polygon layer to 50% (works in both project and layout views) but when I regenerate and export an atlas, those polygons are at 100% opacity again. Is there an option I haven't selected for it to keep the opacity settings?

Using 3.10

[image: Layer Symbology settings]

[image: Export Atlas to PDF settings]

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your settings and of your export options.

Comment: Erik, added screenshots to original post

Answer (score 1):

You can use Layers blending mode setting to multiply instead, it is not the same but the layers beneath will be visible. I prefer blending mode multiply because more details are visible. Opacity is always loosing information. The blending mode "multiply" will be exported as it is with your layout or atlas...

[image]