# QGIS - Shapefile at half opacity in print layout becomes fully opaque when I export as PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf

I have a satellite image of woodland which has a shapefile over the top to show compartments of different species etc.

I have given the compartment shapefile an opacity slider by right clicking on it -> Properties -> Legend -> adding the opacity slider.

I set this slider to around 50% opacity so I can see the underlying satellite imagery as well as the compartment shapefile.

The print layout where I added labels etc shows the correct opacity. However, when I export the map as a pdf, the shapefile opacity becomes 100%, so I cannot see the underlying satellite image.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Half opacity as I would like]

[image: Full opacity when I export as PDF]

Comment: It is easier to adjust the transparency of layers using the symbology tab, and it doesn't lead to such issues.

Comment: what version of qgis are you using?  Past versions did not support transparency in pdf exports, but I'm using 3.16 and transparency is correctly handled in the pdf export.

Comment: @Erik - the transparency slider added to the legend is the same setting as that in symbology tab. It just allows access without opening the properties dialog for the layer.

Comment: @Llaves 3.16.7 (Hannover) is my version. Maybe going slightly earlier would fix the issue?

Comment: @Tree01 - works for me on 3.16.7 on Windows. I select "create geospatial pdf". From the main canvas window I can also Project->Export->Export map to  PDF, again select create geospatial PDF, don't select rasterize. In both cases the resulting PDF has a transparent layer that can be toggled on/off in the pdf viewer layer selector.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on google - had to change the blending mode to 'multiply' and that worked.

[QGIS - Layer Rendering Opacity not being kept when exporting atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387589/qgis-layer-rendering-opacity-not-being-kept-when-exporting-atlas)